# MySQL Insert multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a setting table and am trying to insert data settings for a user.

Table:

```
id (userid)|keyword|data|flags (setting id)
33         |name   |John|22
33         |sex    |male|21
33         |userid |33  |1
```

I am trying to Insert using this method:

```sql
INSERT INTO users_settings
  (id,keyword, data, flags)
VALUES
 ( '33','name', 'John', '22'),
 ( '33','sex', 'male', '21'),
 ( '33','userid', '33', '1'),
```

But I am getting a MySQL error:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '33-name' for key 'PRIMARY'

the id is not auto inserted (since it's used to hold userid).

my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_settings` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `keyword` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `flags` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`keyword`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What is your table schema? Id is auto_increment?

Comment: Unless `id` is a character (`CHAR` or `VARCHAR`) column, don't quote those values.

Comment: I think Primary, as the error is related to Primary

Comment: Can you give your table schema?

Comment: `id varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci`   `keyword varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci`    `data varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci flags int(1)`

Comment: @EdCottrell `id` is `VARCHAR`

Comment: @user1741397 You need to post your entire schema (the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name`) in your question (not in the comments).  Also, post the actual error message that you are getting. Off the top of my head, `flags` is an `int` datatype, so stop quoting those values in your query. That's probably part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the column flags is int

```
INSERT INTO users_settings
  (id,keyword, data, flags)
VALUES
 ( '31','name', 'John', 22),
 ( '32','sex', 'male', 21),
 ( '33','userid', '33', 1)
```

Comment: i am still getting `#1062 - Duplicate entry '33-name' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: make it with different primary key then

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think TWO problems here;

1) your ID (used id ) field might be Primary Key.

2) You are trying to insert CHAR in INT filed of flag.

So please Try;

```
INSERT INTO user_settings
  (id,keyword, data, flags)
VALUES
  ( '31','name', 'John', 22),
  ( '32','sex', 'male', 21),
  ( '33','userid', '33', 1);
```

**EDIT:**

check this [SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22481) it works perfectly,

only one thing, create table has name **user_settings** and you insert have table name **users_settings**. Otherwise it worked perfectly...!!

Comment: There is no any issue to insert of `insert CHAR in INT filed of flag.` It works.

Comment: i removed the id column (just for test) from insert also removed '' from flags as you suggesting, i am getting diffrent error now `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''keyword', 'data','flags') VALUES ('name', 'John', 22), ('sex', 's' at line 2`

Comment: Ok, will you please SHOW you Table schema ?

Comment: @Sadikhasan, may be if you have checked that, I have never tried that..!!

Comment: @user2767299 i have posted my table schema, id and keyword are primary what that really means?

Comment: check EDIT and look at SQL link, above insert should work..!!

Comment: Thanks :) so many hints got me closer and closer, i did had few times typo mistakes, in addition seems between the errors it did insert one row. buttom line: i found that i should order the FLAG numbers from lowest number to higher - i kinda of feel why but still can't put it in words yet :)

Comment: So are you sorted Now ? Vote if I have helped you ..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in inserting of your data.

You have made the candidate key by taking combination of two fields as primary key.

when we define more than 1 key then combination of primary keys are always said to be the candidate key , In this case you can't insert the record which is having both the values same as inserted before.

After alanysing your answer i can say that you must have inserted the same record before.

this one -> id = 33
         -> keyword = name

So ,try another and different combination of values , i m very sure you will not get any error while inserting.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was this format, and for some reason i had to order them by FLAGS (1-22)

```
INSERT INTO users_settings
  (id,keyword, data, flags)
VALUES
 ( '33','userid', '33', '1'),
 ( '32','sex', 'male', '21'),
 ( '31','name', 'John', '22')
```

Comment: What ? Why you need to order FLAGS ? Dose not make any sense.